# During RPT run, driver has reported that it is no longer receiving messages from the workbench

Tags: java, http, performance-testing, rpt, rational-performance-test

I am using RPT8.3 in which I am running a schedule in RPT having 100 users which have to run until finished with no ramp up. The structure of schedule is :

```
-schedule (100 users)
   |
   |-User group(100% users)
          |
          |-6 recorded scripts...
```

I am using same machine for running the application under test in which RPT is installed i.e. workbench and agent are same machine.

The schedule ran for near about 3 Hrs and then it gave following error:

*Test Run stopped due to error.Driver localhost has reported that it is no longer receiving messages from the workbench.  The previous message received from this driver, 2683 milliseconds ago, was KEEP_ALIVE.  The last message sent to this driver, 3556 milliseconds ago, was USERSTATES,100,100,0,User Group 1,100,100,0.*

What could be the possible reasons that driver has stopped receiving the messages from workbench?

Also it is using **KEEP_ALIVE** in the above error message. What does this  mean?

I have analyzed the memory and CPU usage during schedule run by windows task manager. CPU usage was very less than 100% and also no memory problem.

I am using windows7 and RPT8.3.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, the most likely reason is that the workbench JVM has started having memory issues. The workbench log (Error log view in workbench or .log file in /path/to/workspace/.metadata) may offer some more clues as to what went wrong.

This [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21660387) provides lots of handy information to troubleshoot.

This [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/optimize-load-handling/) article also talks about best practices for a load test using RPT. Please double-check that your schedule settings follow the optimal settings described there.